# How to shrink the ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, label

I am developing a C#/ASP.NET web application in VS 2008.  Currently this page is too tall.  The buttons appear on top and then there is a large gap between these buttons and the resultLabel text.  The following code is from my ASPX file.  I have tried switching to the Design tab of this file and manually moving this label, but there is still a large gap.  I'm sure this is simple.  How do I correct this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataMatch.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddFileToSQL.DataMatch" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <table width="50%" >
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <asp:placeholder runat="server" id="phTextBoxes"></asp:placeholder>
            </td>
             <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="Instructions" runat="server" Font-Italic="True"  
                    Text="Now select from the dropdownlists which table columns from my database you want to map these fields to"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="2" >
                <asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit" width="150px" style="top:auto; left:auto"
                    OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" top="100px"></asp:button>
                &nbsp;
                </td>
       </tr>
     <asp:panel id="pnlDisplayData" runat="server" visible="False">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">
                <asp:literal id="lTextData" runat="server"></asp:literal>
            </td>
        </tr></asp:panel>
    </table> 

    <table align="center"><tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;width: 300px;">
    <asp:Label ID="resultLabel" runat="server" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;" 
        Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </td></tr></table>    
    <p>
</p>      
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you've got some inline CSS.

Remove the:

```
 top:148px;
```

And optionally the:

```
 left: 155px;
```

Comment: Thanks but this still isn't working for me.  Would you please see my revised code above?

Comment: alas, my previous comment didn't get posted. Anyhow, the gist is that I attempted using your exact code (except for the Page directive), but didn't notice anything off. Except that I didn't have any textboxes, but this is because I don't have the information for your placeholder phTextBoxes. If you can provide the actual HTML that would help, do this by viewing your page in a webbrowser and going "View -> Source" paste this to the question and we'll be able to help more. Please also note that to help debug yourself you can use Firebug (FFX plugin) getfirebug.com

Answer (score 0):

Reduce or remove the "top" tag within your asp:Label

```
<asp:Label ID="resultLabel" runat="server" style="position:absolute; text-align:center; top:148px; left: 155px;" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, it is still not fixed after removing the top and left tags.  Can you test out my ASPX code in your VS and see what you get?  I Cleaned the solution and rebuilt it.  I even closed the project and reopened but it still gave me same format.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is to remove the "position:absolute" argument from the style tag.  If you don't need centered text, then just remove the entire style tag from the asp:Label.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Can u test it in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want those 2 tables positioned relative to each other, but try to add border="1" to your table tag to see what is happening with your tables and cells.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it still didn't fix it.  Can u test it in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want your end result to look like, so I don't know why you need two tables.  Will this work for you?  I added in my own text and turned all controls on to visible to see where they would end up on the screen.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    </style> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server"> 
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <asp:placeholder runat="server" id="Placeholder1"></asp:placeholder> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Italic="True"   
                    Text="Now select from the dropdownlists which table columns from my database you want to map these fields to"></asp:Label> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Submit" width="150px"></asp:button> 
            </td> 
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="result"></asp:Label> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <asp:panel id="Panel1" runat="server" visible="true"> 
                <td> 
                    <asp:literal id="Literal1" runat="server" Text="test of literal control"></asp:literal> 
                </td>
            </asp:panel>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things which is kind of not right:

1. You have specified colspan which is not required since you dont have 5 TDs in any TR
2. Inside the table you have given asp Panel. That panel should be inside the td which hosts that literal control.
3. Since you are using tables you are better off not using 
   a. position:absolute
   b. specifying Top

Given below is the corrected html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <table width="50%">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTextBoxes"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Instructions" runat="server" Font-Italic="True" Text="Now select from the dropdownlists which table columns from my database you want to map these fields to"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="center" >
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="150px" ></asp:Button>                
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlDisplayData" runat="server" Visible="False">
                    <asp:Literal ID="lTextData" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </asp:Panel>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">
                <asp:Label ID="resultLabel" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;"
                    Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Also check if you are repositioning any of the items in code behind.**

HTH